# Is it possible to program and check invariants in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, invariants, theorem-proving

When I write an algorithm I usually write down invariants in comments.

For example, one function might return an ordered list, and the other one expect that a list would be ordered.
I'm aware that theorem provers exists, but I have no experience using them.

I also believe that smart compiler [sic!] can make use of them to optimize the program.
So, is it possible to write down invariants and make compiler check them?

Comment: There has been some work on "extended static checking" - e.g. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/verify/index.htm plus work on contracts by Ralf Hinze and others. Current practice seems to be to enforce invariants with the type system. i.e. making an opaque newtype for an ordered list and only exporting constructors that build one correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, the answer is yes and no. There's no way to just write an invariant separate from a type and check it. There was an implementation of this in a research fork of Haskell called ESC/Haskell, however: http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1689

You do have various other options. For one, you can use asserts: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/assertions.html

Then with the appropriate flag, you can turn off these asserts for production.

More generally, you can encode the invariants in your types. I was going to add more here, but dons beat me to the punchlines.

One more example is this very nice encoding of red-black trees: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/ti5il/redblack_trees_in_haskell_using_gadts_existential/

Comment: I was looking for the GADTs tree example. Good spot.

Comment: Looks like combination of types and asserts is good enough. I wish it were possible to check these asserts in compile time. For example in `(!!) :: [a] -> b -> a` check whether `b < length a` stays true.

Comment: Andrew: Take a look at the "statically checked array access" example in don's post. Also see the blas and hmatrix-static libraries on hackage which use types to make sure sizes match in matrix and vector operations.

Comment: @Andrew: in the limit you need a dependent type system to verify things like that, and it's not something the compiler can just do for you with no extra work on your part; you the programmer must _prove_ that everywhere you use `(!!)`, you are passing an index that is in bounds. Haskell represents a pretty sweet spot in terms of what can be verified both statically _and_ automatically.

Answer (score 60):

The following is a stunt, but it's quite a safe stunt so do try it at home. It uses some of the entertaining new toys to bake *order* invariants into mergeSort.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, PolyKinds, KindSignatures, MultiParamTypeClasses,
    FlexibleInstances, RankNTypes, FlexibleContexts #-}
```

I'll have natural numbers, just to keep things simple.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

But I'll define `<=` in type class Prolog, so the typechecker can try to figure order out implicitly.

```
class LeN (m :: Nat) (n :: Nat) where
instance             LeN Z n where
instance LeN m n =>  LeN (S m) (S n) where
```

In order to sort numbers, I need to know that any two numbers can be ordered *one way or the other*. Let's say what it means for two numbers to be so orderable.

```
data OWOTO :: Nat -> Nat -> * where
  LE :: LeN x y => OWOTO x y
  GE :: LeN y x => OWOTO x y
```

We'd like to know that every two numbers are indeed orderable, provided we have a runtime representation of them. These days, we get that by building the *singleton family* for `Nat`. `Natty n` is the type of runtime copies of `n`.

```
data Natty :: Nat -> * where
  Zy :: Natty Z
  Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)
```

Testing which way around the numbers are is quite a lot like the usual Boolean version, except with evidence. The step case requires unpacking and repacking because the types change. Instance inference is good for the logic involved.

```
owoto :: forall m n. Natty m -> Natty n -> OWOTO m n
owoto Zy      n       = LE
owoto (Sy m)  Zy      = GE
owoto (Sy m)  (Sy n)  = case owoto m n of
  LE -> LE
  GE -> GE
```

Now we know how to put numbers in order, let's see how to make ordered lists. The plan is to describe what it is to be in order *between loose bounds*. Of course, we don't want to exclude any elements from being sortable, so the type of *bounds* extends the element type with bottom and top elements.

```
data Bound x = Bot | Val x | Top deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

I extend the notion of `<=` accordingly, so the typechecker can do bound checking.

```
class LeB (a :: Bound Nat)(b :: Bound Nat) where
instance             LeB Bot     b        where
instance LeN x y =>  LeB (Val x) (Val y)  where
instance             LeB (Val x) Top      where
instance             LeB Top     Top      where
```

And here are ordered lists of numbers: an `OList l u` is a sequence `x1 :< x2 :< ... :< xn :< ONil` such that `l <= x1 <= x2 <= ... <= xn <= u`. The `x :<` checks that `x` is above the lower bound, then imposes `x` as the lower bound on the tail.

```
data OList :: Bound Nat -> Bound Nat -> * where
  ONil :: LeB l u => OList l u
  (:<) :: forall l x u. LeB l (Val x) =>
          Natty x -> OList (Val x) u -> OList l u
```

We can write `merge` for ordered lists just the same way we would if they were ordinary. The key invariant is that if both lists share the same bounds, so does their merge.

```
merge :: OList l u -> OList l u -> OList l u
merge ONil      lu         = lu
merge lu        ONil       = lu
merge (x :< xu) (y :< yu)  = case owoto x y of
  LE  -> x :< merge xu (y :< yu)
  GE  -> y :< merge (x :< xu) yu
```

The branches of the case analysis extend what is already known from the inputs with just enough ordering information to satisfy the requirements for the results. Instance inference acts as a basic theorem prover: fortunately (or rather, with a bit of practice) the proof obligations are easy enough.

Let's seal the deal. We need to construct runtime witnesses for numbers in order to sort them this
way.

```
data NATTY :: * where
  Nat :: Natty n -> NATTY

natty :: Nat -> NATTY
natty Z      =                           Nat Zy
natty (S n)  = case natty n of Nat n ->  Nat (Sy n)
```

We need to trust that this translation gives us the `NATTY` that corresponds to the `Nat` we want to sort. This interplay between `Nat`, `Natty` and `NATTY` is a bit frustrating, but that's what it takes in Haskell just now. Once we've got that, we can build `sort` in the usual divide-and-conquer way.

```
deal :: [x] -> ([x], [x])
deal []        = ([], [])
deal (x : xs)  = (x : zs, ys) where (ys, zs) = deal xs

sort :: [Nat] -> OList Bot Top
sort []   = ONil
sort [n]  = case natty n of Nat n -> n :< ONil
sort xs   = merge (sort ys) (sort zs) where (ys, zs) = deal xs
```

I'm often surprised by how many programs that make sense to us can make just as much sense to a typechecker.

[Here's some spare kit I built to see what was happening.

```
instance Show (Natty n) where
  show Zy = "Zy"
  show (Sy n) = "(Sy " ++ show n ++ ")"
instance Show (OList l u) where
  show ONil = "ONil"
  show (x :< xs) = show x ++ " :< " ++ show xs
ni :: Int -> Nat
ni 0 = Z
ni x = S (ni (x - 1))
```

And nothing was hidden.]

Comment: Thank you very much for writing this, this is one of my favourite answers on SO. For the record, compilation requires also `DataKinds` extension. You can also remove `where` and write simply `class LeN (m :: Nat) (n :: Nat)`, `instance LeB Bot b` etc.

Answer (score 26):

Yes.

You encode your invariants in the Haskell type system. The compiler will then enforce (e.g. perform type checking), to prevent your program from compiling if the invariants are not held.

For ordered lists, you might consider a cheap approach of implementing a [smart constructor](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors) which changes the type of a list upon sorting.

```
module Sorted (Sorted, sort) where

newtype Sorted a = Sorted { list :: [a] }

sort :: [a] -> Sorted a
sort = Sorted . List.sort
```

Now you can write functions that assume `Sorted` is held, and the compiler will prevent you passing unsorted things to those functions.

You can go much, much further and encode extremely rich properties into the type system. Examples:

- [statically checked array access](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-static)
- [checked data base access](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MetaHDBC)
- [checked physical dimensions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional)

With practice, quite sophisticated invariants can be enforced by the language, at compile time.

There are limits though, as the type system is not designed so much for proving properties of programs. For heavy duty proofs, consider model checking or theorem proving languages such as Coq. The language Agda is a Haskell-like language whose type system is aimed at proving rich properties.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers here are all fabulous, but even though your question specifically mentioned compiler checking, I feel this page would be incomplete without at least a tip of the hat to [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck).  QuickCheck does its work at runtime instead of in the type system at compile-time, but it's a great tool for testing properties that might be too difficult or inconvenient to express statically in the type system.